# Upgrade to ruby 1.9.3 with rvm or brightbox gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I currently use rvm on my dev box (osx) but I use the system ruby on my server (1.8.7 on Ubuntu 10.04)

I want to upgrade the server to 1.9.3 and have been researching the best way to do it. 
The server is running about four Rails applications all on version 3.2.11.

My options appear to be using rvm or alternatively using the 1.9.3 deb package and the ruby-switch gem provided by BrightBox (who also provide passenger packages)

The Brightbox packages appear to be a clean way to go but I thought I would ask a question here to see if there are any advantages or disadvantages of either approach that I have not thought about.

Answer (score 1):

Rvm is useful when you need to have two or more versions of Ruby on the *same machine*. Development machines tend to have this. There is no need to use a version manager if your production box only requires one version of Ruby.

To this effect, I'd suggest you're correct in doing a single installation from the deb package. I can see the ruby-switch gem gives similar functionality to rvm - up to you as to whether that's important. But if you're using three apps on the same version of ruby, it may not be!

Comment: I used the Brightbox ruby packages but had problems with the passenger package and ended up using the standard passenger gem and install. The ruby-switch functionality seems great for the situation where you want to set the ruby version for the whole server. It is just a wrapper around the "alternatives" system such as used for java version etc.